# NX monorepo fatal: No such ref: 'main~1'

Tags: javascript, git, github-actions, monorepo

I'm trying to build my nx application in github actions with nx cloud enabled. I always get the `fatal: No such ref: 'main~1'` error.

The command `nx affected --target=build --base=main~1 --head=HEAD --parallel --with-deps` works before I commit, but after I commit, the command no longer works locally or in ci.

Based on the docs, setting the base to `main~1` should just compare it to the previous commit of the main branch.

Full error in Github Actions:

```
yarn run v1.22.10
$ nx affected --target=build --base=main~1 --head=HEAD --parallel --with-deps
fatal: Not a valid object name main~1
fatal: No such ref: 'main~1'
nx affected

Run task for affected projects

Run command using --base=[SHA1] (affected by the committed, uncommitted and
untracked changes):
  --base  Base of the current branch (usually master)                   [string]

or using --base=[SHA1] --head=[SHA2] (affected by the committed changes):
  --base  Base of the current branch (usually master)                   [string]
  --head  Latest commit of the current branch (usually HEAD)            [string]

or using:
  --files        Change the way Nx is calculating the affected command by
                 providing directly changed files, list of files delimited by
                 commas                                                  [array]
  --uncommitted  Uncommitted changes                                   [boolean]
  --untracked    Untracked changes                                     [boolean]

Options:
  --help           Show help                                           [boolean]
  --version        Show version number                                 [boolean]
  --target         Task to run for affected projects         [string] [required]
  --parallel       Parallelize the command (default: false)            [boolean]
  --maxParallel    Max number of parallel processes. This flag is ignored if the
                   parallel option is set to `false`. (default: 3)      [number]
  --all            All projects                                        [boolean]
  --exclude        Exclude certain projects from being processed
                                                           [array] [default: []]
  --runner         This is the name of the tasks runner configured in nx.json
                                                                        [string]
  --skip-nx-cache  Rerun the tasks even when the results are available in the
                   cache                              [boolean] [default: false]
  --configuration  This is the configuration to use when performing tasks on
                   projects                                             [string]
  --only-failed    Isolate projects which previously failed
                                                      [boolean] [default: false]
  --verbose        Print additional error stack trace on failure

Error: Command failed: git merge-base --fork-point "main~1" "HEAD"
fatal: No such ref: 'main~1'

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:616:11)
    at Object.execSync (child_process.js:652:15)
    at getFilesUsingBaseAndHead (/home/runner/work/clemento/app/node_modules/@nrwl/workspace/src/command-line/shared.js:55:37)
    at Object.parseFiles (/home/runner/work/clemento/app/node_modules/@nrwl/workspace/src/command-line/shared.js:25:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/work/clemento/app/node_modules/@nrwl/workspace/src/command-line/affected.js:26:112)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/home/runner/work/clemento/app/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:114:62) ***
  status: 128,
  signal: null,
  output: [
    null,
    <Buffer >,
    <Buffer 66 61 74 61 6c 3a 20 4e 6f 20 73 75 63 68 20 72 65 66 3a 20 27 6f 72 69 67 69 6e 2f 6d 61 69 6e 7e 31 27 0a>
  ],
  pid: 1713,
  stdout: <Buffer >,
  stderr: <Buffer 66 61 74 61 6c 3a 20 4e 6f 20 73 75 63 68 20 72 65 66 3a 20 27 6f 72 69 67 69 6e 2f 6d 61 69 6e 7e 31 27 0a>
***
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Workflow File

```
name: Deploy Updated Apps
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - feature/*
      - bugfix/*
      - hotfix/*
      - refactor/*
      - test/*
    paths:
      - "apps/**"
      - "libs/**"
      - .github/**
      - scripts/**
      - package.json
      - workspace.json
      - nx.json
jobs:
  deploy-updated-apps:
    name: Deploy Updated Apps
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      NX_BRANCH: ${{ github.event.number }}
      NX_RUN_GROUP: ${{ github.run_id }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Get Service Account Key
        run: ./scripts/get-service-account.sh
      - name: Login to Google Cloud
        run: ./scripts/login-to-google-cloud.sh
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: yarn install
      - name: Build affected apps
        run: yarn affected:build
```

nx.json

```
{
    "implicitDependencies": {
        "package.json": {
            "dependencies": "*",
            "devDependencies": "*"
        },
        ".eslintrc.json": "*"
    },
    "affected": {
        "defaultBase": "main"
    },
    "npmScope": "someorg",
    "tasksRunnerOptions": {
        "default": {
            "runner": "@nrwl/nx-cloud",
            "options": {
                "cacheableOperations": ["build", "lint", "test", "e2e"],
                "accessToken": "<ACCESS_TOKEN>",
                "canTrackAnalytics": false,
                "showUsageWarnings": true
            }
        }
    },
    "projects": {
        "frontend": {
            "tags": []
        },
        "frontend-e2e": {
            "tags": [],
            "implicitDependencies": ["frontend"]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Okay... so I finally figured out what's going on. After logging `git show-ref` in github actions, I found that the `actions/checkout` action by default only checks out one commit.

> Only a single commit is fetched by default, for the ref/SHA that triggered the workflow.

After specifying the `fetch-depth: 0` to fetch all the refs for all the branches, it worked. Nx is able to properly compare the difference between the different branches and previous commits in the same branch.

```yaml
jobs:
  deploy-updated-apps:
    name: Deploy Updated Apps
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      NX_BRANCH: ${{ github.event.number }}
      NX_RUN_GROUP: ${{ github.run_id }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: yarn install
      - name: Build affected apps
        run: yarn affected:build:branch
```

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "affected:build:branch": "nx affected:build --base=origin/main --head=HEAD --with-deps",
    "affected:build:main": "nx affected:build --base=origin/main~1 --head=HEAD --with-deps",
  },
}
```

Comment: It's also part of the example in the [documentation](https://nx.dev/ci/monorepo-ci-github-actions), but they don't explain why `fetch-depth: 0` is needed. Thanks for clarifying! They also add `- uses: nrwl/nx-set-shas@v2` which according to the [README](https://github.com/nrwl/nx-set-shas) is `a Github Action which sets the base and head SHAs required for "nx affected" commands in CI`.